# How to search text in UIWebView Consists of number of pages and the text should be highlighted in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I parsed epub file into UIWebView.I tried to add UISearchBar for to find text and to be highlighted. For this i added UIWebViewSearch.js file. In my UIWebView i have so many pages. If click on next the next page is displayed or click on previous page previous page ids displayed. For this how to search the text in UIWebView ,How the text will be selected?

If anyone knows please help me.

Thanks in advance...........

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples on the web of JavaScript search and highlight functionalities.

[Here](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm) is an example.

Once you have working JavaScript to search for terms and highlight them in the web page, you will need to call your JS and pass it the text that was entered in the `UISearchBar`.

This can be achieved by using:

```
NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"searchAndHighlight('%@');", yourSearchText];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall];
```

[UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Here i used js file but the text is not finding.in this[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall]; is assigned to NSString .but the string is not displayed. I use ur code but its not working for me. Any other suggestion......

Comment: How are you loading the web pages in the UIWebView ? Are they in the resources of your project or actually on the internet ?

Comment: no. first i converted epub file into aml file. i did parse the xml file into UIWebView consists of number of pages. So in UIWebView consists of number of pages. I tried with js file. but the text is not highlighted.

Comment: How are you linking your JS file in your web page ? Does your JS function get called at all ?